# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mido'

Tags: python, модули

В общем, проблема такова: пытаюсь импортировать модуль mido, но компилятор выдает такую ошибку: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mido'.
Код:

```
from mido import MidiFile

f = str(input('File name: '))
prom = open('path1.txt')
p = prom.read()
fp = p + c
mid = MidiFile(pf, clip=True)
print(mid)
```

Я мог что-то напутать, т.к. информации по этому модулю на русском практически нет, а то что на английском я плохо понимаю.

Comment: Модуль-то установлен вообще?

Comment: Установить: `pip install mido`

Comment: так да я то это уже прописал, а проблема не решилась

Comment: Если у вас несколько версий Python в системе - убедитесь, что установили в нужную. Можете повторить установку конкретно для 3 версии: pip3 install mido

Comment: сmd пишет: Requirement already satisfied:*путь*
Это относится к pip3 и к pip(В принципе логично, ведь я это уже все поставил)

Comment: Тогда попробуйте открыть IDLE для Python 3 (для Windows - пуск, все программы, Python 3, IDLE) и прописать там import mido. Сработает?

Comment: да сработало, но как мне это в pycharm поместить?

Comment: Вам нужно в PyCharm указать нужный интерпретатор. Точно не помню, т.к. сам им не пользуюсь, но залезьте куда-то вроде: File - Settings - Project - Project Interpreter и там укажите путь к вашему Python 3 (python.exe). Этот файл ищите или где-то в Programs Files(x86) - Python, или где-то в C:/Users/Ваше_имя_компа и т.д. Пускай меня поправят юзеры Pycharm

Comment: Да, я понял.. но я пошел хитрее. Зашел в настройки (File - Settings), потом в Project - Project Interpreter, а дальше просто нажал на плюс и добавил модуль mido в pycharm.